# Select2 Remote Data not dynamically creating/selecting option

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am calling an  URL using Ajax to receive data and populate it inside a select element which is using Select2 and remote data.

The remote data is loading absolutely fine when searching inside the select, but with the below code it doesn't seem to be creating/selecting the option inside the for loop.

The console is showing the correct value returned from the Ajax call but it just doesn't select it in the select element

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/section/tickets?action=get_update_details&seq=" + $(el).attr("id"),
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.emails.to !== "") {
                for(var i in data.emails.to) {
                    console.log(data.emails.to[i]);
                    var x = new Option(data.emails.to[i], data.emails.to[i], true, true);
                    $("#contacts_to").append(x).trigger('change');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can u add expected output and actual output?

Comment: the output is in JSON format, that part is working fine. its the adding and selecting options in the select2 box that isn't working but no errors display in the console for that part either

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simulate what you are trying to achieve, can u point out the troubled part.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
    
    const data = ['Remote Data1', 'Remote Data2'];
    
    for(var i in data) {
        var x = new Option(data[i], data[i], true, true);
        $(".js-example-basic-single").append(x).trigger('change');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i wonder if it has something to do with it being remote data instead of data from a variable?

Comment: you should check whether data.emails.to is array of string. if it is array of string, this should work i guess.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to debug without a complete example. However, your code seems to be working fine.

See this modified version:

```js
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      for (let k in data) {

        var x = new Option(data[k], k, true, true);
        $("#contacts_to").append(x).trigger('change');

      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.1.0-beta.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="contacts_to"></select>
```